# Order columns in dataframe based on clients

Tags: python, sorting, dataframe, merge

I have some columns in my dataframe (merged before), say:

`client_10`, `visit_10`, `client_11`, `visit_11`, ...

I need to order the columns like:

`client_1`, `visit_1`, `client_2`, `visit_2`, ...

In each run of code, I may have different number of clients, so no fixed end point.

What is the best way to sort my columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
df = df[sorted(list(df.columns), key=lambda n: (int(n.split('_')[1]), n.split('_')[0]))]
```

- `list(df.columns)` is the list of the columns
- `sorted(...)` sorts them according to the number, then `client`, `visit`
- take `df[...]` on the result, and assign it to `df`

Comment: he wasts the client and the visit one after the other.. 
does this work for the output he wants?

Comment: @YatishKadam Thanks for the comment! Updated

Comment: I have ' invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'STATUS' ' when I add that. Can you please advise?

Comment: @Narg You probably have a column like `client_STATUS` or `visit_STATUS`. What would you like to happen in that case?

Comment: Thank you Ami, I worked on your code and it was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The above answer provided by @https://stackoverflow.com/users/3510736/ami-tavory is better.. 
This another stab at it..

```
ls = ['client_2','visit_3', 'client_1', 'visit_2', 'client_3', 'visit_1']
ls = sorted(list(ls), key=lambda n: (n.split('_')[0], int(n.split('_')[1])))
mid = (len(ls)//2)

print([item for sublist in list(zip(ls[:mid], ls[mid:])) for item in sublist])
>>>['client_1', 'visit_1', 'client_2', 'visit_2', 'client_3', 'visit_3']
```

Comment: I have ' invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'STATUS' ' when I add that. Can you please advise?